# how to disable Data Execution prvention(DEP) in ubuntu to execute shellcode

Tags: ubuntu, nasm, shellcode, dep

am using ubuntu 14.04, 64bit.
i am studying shellcode writing. So to spawn a shell i wrote the following program

```
segment .text
global _start:
_start:


jmp short GotoCall

shellcode:
    pop esi
    xor eax, eax
    mov byte [esi + 7], al          #here i get Error
    lea ebx, [esi]
    mov long [esi + 8], ebx
    mov long [esi + 12], eax

    mov byte al, 0x0b
    mov ebx, esi
    lea ecx, [esi + 8]
    lea edx, [esi + 12]     
    int 80h

GotoCall:
    call shellcode
    Db '/bin/shJAAAABBBB'
```

Compiled -> nasm -ggdb -f elf Shellcode_Execve.asm

Linked ->   ld -m elf_i386 -ggdb -o Shellcode_Execve Shellcode_Execve.o

When i ran it in GDB, i found in below instruction i get error,

```
mov byte [esi + 7], al
```

i found that, this is because of DEP(DATA EXECUTION PREVENTION).
So i tried "-fno-stack-protector -z execstack" to compile and link like below,

```
$ nasm -ggdb -f elf32 -z execstack Shellcode_Execve.asm
nasm: error: unrecognised option `-z'
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
type `nasm -h' for help

$ nasm -ggdb -f elf32 -z execstack -o shell Shellcode_Execve.asm
nasm: error: unrecognised option `-z'
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
type `nasm -h' for help

$ nasm -ggdb -z execstack -f elf32  -o shell Shellcode_Execve.asm
nasm: error: unrecognised option `-z'
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
type `nasm -h' for help

$ nasm -ggdb  -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -z execstack -f elf32  -o shell Shellcode_Execve.asm
nasm: fatal: unrecognised output format `no-stack-protector' - use -hf for a list
type `nasm -h' for help

$ nasm -ggdb -f elf32 Shellcode_Execve.asm

$ gcc -ggdb -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o Shellcode_Execve Shellcode_Execve.o
Shellcode_Execve.o:Shellcode_Execve.asm:5: multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ nasm -ggdb -f elf32 Shellcode_Execve.asm

$ gcc -ggdb -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o Shellcode_Execve Shellcode_Execve.o

$ ./Shellcode_Execve 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ nasm -ggdb -f elf32 Shellcode_Execve.asm

$ ld -m elf_i386 -ggdb -z execstack -o Shellcode_Execve Shellcode_Execve.o

$ ./Shellcode_Execve 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

like above i tried all the ways to disable DEP using GCC and ld.
But nothing works. So how can i disable DEP? and make my Code working?
(please make sure the problem is of DEP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have changed my NASM code a little bit now it looks like below,

```
section .mytext progbits alloc exec write align=16  ; CHANGED HERE
    global _start:
_start:
    jmp short GotoCall

    shellcode:
        pop esi
        xor eax, eax
        mov byte [esi + 7], al
        lea ebx, [esi]
        mov long [esi + 8], ebx
        mov long [esi + 12], eax

        mov byte al, 0x0b
        mov ebx, esi
        lea ecx, [esi + 8]
        lea edx, [esi + 12]        
        int 80h

    GotoCall:
        call shellcode
        Db '/bin/shJAAAABBBB'
```

The .text section is not writable by default. Just changed the first line to

> "section .mytext progbits alloc exec write align=16 "

[for details about progbits alloc exec write,please click here.](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2)

And the linker has some default override so it ignores writable .text even if you ask for it. But it doesn't care if it has a different name.

now compile and link it,

```
nasm -f elf32 Shellcode_Execve.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o Shellcode_Execve Shellcode_Execve.o
```

Now it WORKSSSS:)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late but I have been battling with this same code and the gcc stack protections. When turning it into shellcode with objdump -d I ended up with:

```
char shellcode[]="\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

int main()
{
    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Then, with the help of your tips I was able to compile and run it with:

> ~/Shellcode$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack execShellSpawn.c -o execShellSpawn

Without -z execstack I get a Segfault.
Without -fno-stack-protector it accomplishes about as much as exit(0).